# Connecting to mysql from cygwin issue

Tags: mysql, cygwin, command-prompt

I am trying to debug something larger and I noticed that I can not properly connect to mysql from cygwin. I run the command by providing the host, user and password, and the only output is the error:
`Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`
after which it just idles.

interesting is that when i run
`which mysql` and I go to that path with the command prompt from windows and run the same command everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Some console applications that weren't compiled using Cygwin may work incorrectly inside Cygwin's terminal. MySQL client is probably one of them. To use MySQL client with Cygwin, I'd install one from official Cygwin's repositories rather than trying to use native Windows MySQL. (Note that this doesn't mean installing whole server, just the client.)

Comment: I have tried reinstalling the client, but with no success

Comment: to be clear, that's the instance of mysql which works from the dos command prompt...